# Compose maps using key and value in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I have two maps and I want to merge using some rules

```
val a = mapOf(1 to 101, 2 to 102, 3 to 103)
val b = mapOf(101 to "a", 102 to "b", 103 to "c")
```

is there a way to merge using values for **a** and key for **b**

```
val result = mapOf(1 to "A", 2 to "b", 3 to "c")
```

Comment: What if there are values in `a` that doesn't exist as keys in `b`? What if there is `4 to 104` in `a`, but there is no key `104` in `b`? What about if there are extra keys in `b` that doesn't exist as values in `a`?

Comment: Not my case, all values in **a** is on **b**, no extra keys on **b**

Comment: Would ‘compose’ be a better term than ‘concatenate’ for this question?

Comment: you're right, I fixed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the values of `a` and the keys of `b` will always match, you can do this with a single `mapValues`

```
val result = a.mapValues { (_, v) -> b.getValue(v) }
```

`getValue` can be safely used here since the key `v` always exist in `b` as a consequence of our assumption.

In general, if `b` may not have all the values of `a` as keys, you can do:

```
val result = a.entries.mapNotNull { (k, v) -> b[v]?.let { k to it } }.toMap()
```

This removes the key from the result, if the key's corresponding value in `a` doesn't exist as a key in `b`. You can also use this as an alternative if you don't like the `!!` in the first solution.

`mapNotNull` and `toMap` loops through the entries one time each. If that is a problem for you, use `asSequence`:

```
a.asSequence().mapNotNull { (k, v) -> b[v]?.let { k to it } }.toMap()
```

Comment: You can also use `getValue` instead of `[]!!`.

Comment: @MichaelKrussel Thanks! I didn't know that until now!

Answer (score 1):

Since you're sure each value from map `a` is present in map `b`, this should be as simple as using `mapValues` and using the value of that key in map b

```
a.mapValues { entry ->
    b[entry.value]
}
```

Due to having to edit and redo my answer, @Sweeper beat me to it and provided a more in-depth answer.